# Wildcard search multi select fields

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

Is is possible to use wildcards in where statements on multi-select fields

I tried a simple

Select Id, Name from Positions_*c where Industry*_c includes(:selectedIndustry)

this works

but if i want to pass a wildcard in with :selectedIndustry it breaks?

Comment: What are you using for your value of `selectedIndustry` in this example? And what is the error it's failing with? I was able to get this working in the developer console, so it may just be that you're passing in something unexpected.

Comment: I'm trying to get it work just passing in a wildcard like '%' and nothing else

Comment: To my knowledge you can only use the wildcard with a `like` expression. `includes` is a different story, and you're pretty limited with what you can do with it at this point. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_querying_multiselect_picklists.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to combine the use of LIKE and % in collections.

```
You have to populate the sets with % first and then use LIKE to query.

    setAccNames.add('%'+'ABC'+'%');
    setAccNames.add('%'+'XYZ'+'%');
    setAccNames.add('%'+'RST'+'%');

    List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :setAccNames];
```

Here's more on this:

https://sfdcfanboy.wordpress.com/2016/03/01/use-like-and-in-in-a-single-soql-query/

Answer (score 0):

I don,t think that you can use wild card with the include tag in SOQL but you can use the query in two ways :

```
1. Industry_c Like :'%'+selectedIndustry+'%'

2.Set<String> industryValues = new Set<String>{'%selectedIndustry'};

 Select Id, Name from Positions_c where Industry_c includes(:industryValues)
```